# Can you preview physics bakes as they're baking?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation, soft-body

I'm baking some pretty long soft body and rigid body sims and quite often something goes horribly wrong during the bake and it doesn't operate correctly, this is fine, however I feel like I could save heaps of time if blender would preview each frame of the bake as it was going. I have the flip fluids addon from BlenderMarket and this lets me preview the sim as it's going, but it seems like the built in sims that ship with blender dont support this. Is there any way to make this happen?

Thanks!

Comment: just change your end frame before baking to a much lower number, then you can check it earlier. If it is ok, just raise end frame and tap resume baking.